# How to remove turtle list in an effective way

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm doing a snake game in a way of attaching turtles together and move each of them individually each time. Let's say we have a white snake on a black screen which consists of multiple adjacent 'square' turtles. If the snake move and hit the wall, it should be removed. So what's the best way to do it? Loop through all segments and use hideturtle() to hide each turtle element? Or simply move every segment out of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be when the brick moves and hits the wall it has each segment be set to invisible. These can all be cleaned up or removed at an intermediary screen like a play again/etc

Comment: the game will keep running when the snake hit the wall. But yes I personally feel using hideturtle() is the easiest way.